# Source code hiding in plain sight or disappearing into a cloak of invisibility

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-intent, android-activity

The last time I ran my app, it moved from the first/primary Activity to the next one, as it should 
have, when I selected a button to perform that Intent.

Now, however, the debugger opens up and I get a slew of messages in the Debug tab. The first one,
representative of the rest, says, "ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(IBinder, boolean) line: 2120"
???

It says, "Source not found" with an "Edit Source Lookup Path" button below it in Debug view which opens when I try to move to the next Activity from the main one. As stated, it worked just fine the last time I worked on this app (a few days ago), and the location of the source hasn't moved, so how could that be the case...???

When I then switch back from Debug perspective to Java perspective in Eclipse, I get:
"The app has stopped unexpectedly. Force close?"

Comment: if you getting force close can you put the stack trace from logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my declaring a SharedPreferences object:

```
SharedPreferences KITPrefs;
```

...but then failing to instantiate it was the culprit. Now that I've added:

```
KITPrefs = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

...it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried cleaning the project? mine was force closing out of nowhere before, and once I cleaned it, it stopped. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all try cleaning the project. Secondly I have came across the same errors,Android has a great framework to work in. However, it is in its infancy and debugging my code has been a very big problem for me. Whenever something goes wrong in the code, I always get "source not found" error. It doesn't tell me I have a nullPointer exception , or string is incomplete.  No matter what's wrong with the code, I always get "source not found" error. The reason that happens is Android doesn't pack the source along with the application it sends to the emulator (maybe they should do that for a debugging run). After searching the net for a while, I came across this solution - wrap your code in a try and catch block and then log the exception to console. By doing so you will exactly know from where the error is getting generated.

"Source Not Found" just means the line of code that generated the exception is in a binary file. It does exist, Eclipse just can't show it to you.